# why is my function not define?

Tags: python, class

```
import re, traceback, keyword

def pnamedtuple(type_name, field_names, mutable=False):
    def show_listing(s):
        for i, l in enumerate(s.split('\n'), 1):
            print('{num: >4} {txt}'.format(num= i, txt= l.rstrip()))


    class type_name:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self._fields = [x,y]
            self._mutable = False

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Point(x={x},y={y})'.format(x=self.x,y=self.y)

        def get_x(self):
            return self.x

        def get_y(self):
            return self.y

        def __getitem__(self, i):
            if i == 0:
                i = "x"
            elif i == 1:
                i = "y"

            if i == "x":
                return self.get_x()
            elif i == "y":
                return self.get_y()
            else:
                raise IndexError("Invalid key: {}".format(i))

        def __eq__(self,right):
            if self[1] == right[1]:
                return True
            return False

        def _replace(self,**kargs ):
            for key, value in kargs.iteritems():
                z = zip(key,value)
            for x in z:
                for y in self.field:
                    if x[0] == y:
                        self.x = x[1]
                    if x[0] == y:
                        self.y = x[1]

    name_space = dict(__name__='pnamedtuple_{type_name}'.format(type_name= type_name))
    try:
        exec(class_definition,name_space)
        name_space[type_name].source_code = class_definition
    except(SyntaxError, TypeError):
        show_listing(class_definition)
        traceback.print_exc()
    return name_space[type_name]
```

The header is def pnamedtuple(type_name, field_names, mutable=False): an example call to this function is

```
Point = pnamedtuple('Point', ['x','y'], mutable=False)
```

, which is equivalent to writing

```
Point = pnamedtuple('Point', 'x y') 
Point = pnamedtuple('Point', 'x,y')
```

A legal name for the type and fields must start with a letter which can be followed by 0 or more letters, digits, or underscore characters

field_names must be a list of legal names, such as  ['x','y'] or 'x y', or 'x, y'

p = Point(1,2) writing p.get_x(), or p[0]), or p['x'] returns a result of 1

new_origin = origin._replace(y=5), then print(origin,new_origin) would display as Point(x=0,y=0) Point(x=0,y=5)

however, when I run this function, it shows that everything is not defined.
I added the bsc.txt code below, it is a little bit long:

```
 6 # Test pnamedtuple (as pnt)
 7 *Error: Triple1    = pnt('Triple1', 'a b c') raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
 8 *Error: print(Triple1.source_code) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
 9 *Error: Triple2    = pnt('Triple2', 'a,  b,    c') raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
10 *Error: Triple3    = pnt('Triple3', ['a','b','c']) raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
11 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt(1, 'a b c') raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
12 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt('Triple_Bad', {'a','b','c'}) raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
13 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt('3', 'a b c') raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
14 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt('Triple_Bad', 'a 3 c') raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
15 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt('Triple_Bad', 'a b if') raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
16 *Error: Triple_Bad = pnt('Triple_Bad', '_a _b _c') raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: SyntaxError
17 *Error: Triple_OK  = pnt('Triple_OK', 'a17 b__1 c__2') raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
18 # Test init/repr
19 *Error: t1 = Triple1(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
20 *Error: repr(t1) raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
21 *Error: t2 = Triple2(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple2' is not defined
22 *Error: repr(t2) raised exception NameError: name 't2' is not defined
23 *Error: t3 = Triple3(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple3' is not defined
24 *Error: repr(t3) raised exception NameError: name 't3' is not defined
25 *Error: t3 = Triple3(c=3,b=2,a=1) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple3' is not defined
26 *Error: repr(t3) raised exception NameError: name 't3' is not defined
27 *Error: tok= Triple_OK(c__2=3,b__1=2,a17=1) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple_OK' is not defined
28 *Error: repr(tok) raised exception NameError: name 'tok' is not defined
29 *Error: t1.a raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
30 *Error: t1.b raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
31 *Error: t1.c raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
32 *Error: t1.d raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: AttributeError
33 # Test get_ methods
34 *Error: t1.get_a() raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
35 *Error: t1.get_b() raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
36 *Error: t1.get_c() raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
37 *Error: t1.get_d() raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: AttributeError
38 *Error: l = [Triple1(a=1,b=2,c=3),Triple1(b=1,c=2,a=3),Triple1(c=1,a=2,b=3)] raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
39 *Error: l.sort(key=Triple1.get_a) raised exception NameError: name 'l' is not defined
40 *Error: l raised exception NameError: name 'l' is not defined
41 # Test __getitem__ functions
42 *Error: t1[0] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
43 *Error: t1[1] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
44 *Error: t1[2] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
45 *Error: t1['a'] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
46 *Error: t1['b'] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
47 *Error: t1['c'] raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
48 *Error: t1[4] raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: IndexError
49 *Error: t1['d'] raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: IndexError
50 *Error: t1[3.2] raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: IndexError
51 # Test ==
52 *Error: t1 == t1 raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
53 *Error: t1 == t2 raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
54 *Error: t1 == Triple1(a=1,b=2,c=3) raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
55 *Error: t1 == Triple1(a=1,b=1,c=3) raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
56 # Test replace (not mutable)
57 *Error: t1._replace(a=2) raised exception; unevaluated: Triple1(2,2,3)
58 *Error: t1._replace(a=2,c=2) raised exception; unevaluated: Triple1(2,2,2)
59 *Error: t1._replace(a=2,c=2,d=2) raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: TypeError
60 *Error: t1 raised exception; unevaluated: Triple1(a=1,b=2,c=3)
61 # Test _replace (mutable)
62 *Error: Triple1 = pnt('Triple1', 'a b c',mutable=True) raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
63 *Error: t1 = Triple1(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
64 *Error: t1._replace(a=2,c=2) raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
65 *Error: t1 raised exception; unevaluated: Triple1(a=2,b=2,c=2)
66 # Test Extra Credit (prohibit mutation if immutable)
67 *Error: Triple1 = pnt('Triple1', 'a b c',mutable=False) raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
68 *Error: t1 = Triple1(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
69 *Error: t1.a = 2 raised wrong exception(NameError) should be from list: AttributeError
70 *Error: Triple1 = pnt('Triple1', 'a b c',mutable=True) raised exception NameError: name 'class_definition' is not defined
71 *Error: t1 = Triple1(1,2,3) raised exception NameError: name 'Triple1' is not defined
72 *Error: t1.a = 2 raised exception NameError: name 't1' is not defined
73 *Error: t1 raised exception; unevaluated: Triple1(2,2,3)
```

can someon tell me why am I getting all of these errors? Is it because there is something is wrong with my typename? Can someone tell me how to fix it? thanks a lot.

this is the base code I was provided:

```
import re, traceback, keyword

def pnamedtuple(type_name, field_names, mutable=False):
    def show_listing(s):
        for i, l in enumerate(s.split('\n'), 1):
            print('{num: >4} {txt}'.format(num= i, txt= l.rstrip()))

# put your code here
# bind class_definition (used below) to the string constructed for the class


# For initial debugging, always show the source code of the class
#show_listing(class_definition)

# Execute the class_definition string in a local namespace, binding the
#   name source_code in its dictionary to the class_defintion; return the
#   class object created; if there is a syntax error, list the class and
#   also show the error
    name_space = dict(__name__='pnamedtuple_{type_name}'.format(type_name= type_name))
    try:
        exec(class_definition,name_space)
        name_space[type_name].source_code = class_definition
    except(SyntaxError, TypeError):
        show_listing(class_definition)
        traceback.print_exc()
    return name_space[type_name]
```

Comment: Why are you defining a class within a method?

Comment: Yeah that is probably giving you 73 errors... don't do that

Comment: I thought that is the requirement, it that not correct?

Comment: @EliSadoff Man are you narrow-minded. Open your spirit to the possibilities the great Python offers you.

Comment: I don't really think you can name a class like that...

Comment: oppos, I missed some code. I added in the below.

Comment: but it is the requirement to define a class like that, otherwise the code in the below will not work

Comment: @Rightleg How would that scoping even work?

Comment: @zeyuxie Define the class outside of the method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also, you never defined a `class_definition` variable...

Comment: @EliSadoff Well, I don't feel like trying such a thing, and I don't know if Python supports it, but semantically speaking, it just means you (don't take it personally) define a class that exists only in a method. Okay, I really can't see how it could be useful, but it does make sense.

Comment: @Rightleg I won't take it personally. It seems like something that should never be done.

Comment: hey guys, I added the base code I got. I have to define the class based on it. I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: I tried to define the class outside of the function, but for the return name_space[type_name] in the last line, I got the SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.

Comment: @zeyuxie Seriously, get that class out of this method. In the best case, it is useless. In the most likely case, it will confuse you and give you lots of bugs.

Comment: @zeyuxie `return` is a statement that terminates a function, and nothing more. So it __has__ at the end of a function. You must have done it wrong.

Comment: the base code is provided, I did not do the base code. I was just asked to define a class base on the code I got.

Comment: it's a very interesting problem and you can absolutely have the class definition in the function. Do you want to dynamically instantiate new types? Can you provide one of the source code files (e.g.: Point.txt)? @EliSadoff don't mix up function and method in this context, it actually matters.

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny I don't have that actually, point is just an example, the type_name can be anything you want. I think the reason for defining this class in the function is because this function actually return a class, see the last line return name_space[type_name]

Comment: if you don't have dynamic source code why not just return the class itself? I'm really unsure what you're trying to do. You have an `exec` statement, that implies for me  executing python code loaded via `open` instead of `import`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your class definition is or where you get it from, it would be very helpful if you post it. I suppose you have some source code lying around and are supposed to wrap it in a class that inherits from the baseclass in your function.

I call the baseclass `irrelevant` because the name literally doesn't matter, it will only be resolved within the function scope, which is kind of what the commentors are saying. For your case the fact that it can't be resolved in outer scope is not only acceptable, but intended.

This code will do what you expect it to do I suppose:

```
import re, traceback, keyword


def pnamedtuple(type_name, field_names, mutable=False):
    def show_listing(s):
        for i, l in enumerate(s.split('\n'), 1):
            print('{num: >4} {txt}'.format(num= i, txt= l.rstrip()))


    class irrelevant:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self._fields = [x,y]
            self._mutable = False

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Point(x={x},y={y})'.format(x=self.x,y=self.y)

        def get_x(self):
            return self.x

        def get_y(self):
            return self.y

        def __getitem__(self, i):
            if i == 0:
                i = "x"
            elif i == 1:
                i = "y"

            if i == "x":
                return self.get_x()
            elif i == "y":
                return self.get_y()
            else:
                raise IndexError("Invalid key: {}".format(i))

        def __eq__(self,right):
            if self[1] == right[1]:
                return True
            return False

        def _replace(self,**kargs ):
            for key, value in kargs.iteritems():
                z = zip(key,value)
            for x in z:
                for y in self.field:
                    if x[0] == y:
                        self.x = x[1]
                    if x[0] == y:
                        self.y = x[1]

    name_space = dict(__name__='pnamedtuple_{type_name}'.format(type_name= type_name),irrelevant=irrelevant)
    class_definition = "class Point(irrelevant):\n    pass"

    try:
        exec(class_definition,name_space)
        name_space[type_name].source_code = class_definition
    except(SyntaxError, TypeError):
        show_listing(class_definition)
        traceback.print_exc()
    return name_space[type_name]

Point = pnamedtuple('Point', ['x','y'], mutable=False)
p = Point(1,2)
print(p.get_x())
```

The trick is to execute your code while passing the baseclass in the your context. Depending on the initial contents of `class_definition` the code might have to change.

Brilliant question, where did you get this assignment?

Comment: Hi, This is actually my homework assignment, this is what the class will do:

Comment: Write a function named pnamedtuple that is passed information about a named tuple: it returns a reference to a class object from which we can construct instances of the specified named tuple. We might use this class as follows: from pcollections import pnamedtuple
Point = pnamedtuple('Point', 'x y')
p = Point(0,0)

Comment: also,  i dont think you can change the base code, it still shows undefined after I change the code you provided.

Comment: I mean that's  what they told you to do, but why would you do this? You could do this much more simply by just returning the class itself rather than doing some weird `exec`